# Python accessor and mutator methods

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a Python question that was described as follows:

> Design a class that holds the following personal data: name, address,
>   age, and phone number. Write appropriate accessor and mutator methods.
>   Also, write a program that creates three instances of the class. One
>   instance should hold your information, and the other two should hold
>   your friends’ or family members’ information.

I am stumped on where to go from here. I think I have 90% correct but I am missing the main function code. My code is as follows:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, address, age, phone):
        self.__name = name
        self.__address = address
        self.__age = age
        self.__phone_number = phone

    #Set methods
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name   
    def set_address(self,address):
        self.__address = address
    def set_age(self,age):
        self.__age = age
    def set_phone(self,phone):
        self.__phone = phone


    #Get methods
    def get_name(self):
        reurn self.__name
    def get_address(self):
        reurn self.__address      
    def get_age(self):
        reurn self.__age
    def get_phone(self):
        reurn self.__phone

def main():

#not sure what to put here?????

main()
```

Comment: You've done all the hard work just create 3 instances. So `me = Person('name', 'address', 20, 'me@xyz.com')` with the right data.

Comment: Not sure about it, but "appropriate accessor and mutator methods" may involve `@property` and `@x.setter`. Have a look at [this post](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the blueprint for your objects. That's your `Person` class. Now it's time to build some `Person`'s. You can do that with

```
p1 = Person("Your Name", "Address", 12, "phone_number")
p2 = etc
p3 = etc
```

You can access your getter and setter methods from your objects e.g.

```
p1.set_name("Joe")
print(p1.get_name()) # outputs "Joe"
```